# Background image not fitting the whole width of the browser?

Tags: css

This is my code:

```
#content{
background-image:    url('../images/hero.jpg');
background-size:     cover;                   
background-repeat:   no-repeat;
width:100%;
height: 550px;
}
```

why does it not fit the screen with 100% width and with cover?

Comment: Can you provide more markup? Hard to tell what the `#content` is actually filling if there's more to the document.

Comment: Try `body {padding: 0; margin: 0}`

Comment: Could you post some html

Comment: You should create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @lolka_bolka thanks! the problem was there

Answer (score 0):

You set width 100% on #content, not on background. Try this:

```
#content {
background: url('/images/bg.png') no-repeat center center fixed;

-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
}
```